# Sharing DB queries in Node.js methods

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, knex.js

What's the best practice for sharing DB query code between multiple Node.js Express controller methods? I’ve searched but the samples I’ve found don’t really get into this.

For example, I have this getUser method (using Knex for MySQL) that makes a call to get user info. I want to use it in other methods but I don't need all the surrounding stuff like the response object.

```
export let getUser = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        knex.select().where('email', req.params.email)
            .table('users')
            .then( (dbResults) => {
            const results: IUser = dbResults[0];
            res
                .status(200)
                .set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'close' })
                .send(results);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({ error: "Error getting person" + req.params.email });
        return next(err);
    }
};
```

It seems wrong to repeat the query code somewhere else where I need to get the user. Should I turn my DB query code into async functions like this example and then call them from within the controller methods that use the query? Is there a simpler way?

```
/**
 * @param {string} email
 */
async function getUserId(email: string) {
    try {
        return await knex.select('id')
            .where('email', email)
            .table('users');
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example create "service" modules, which contain helpers for certain type of queries. Or you could use ORM and implement special queries in each model that is called "fat model" design. Pretty much anything goes as long as you remember to not create new knex instance in every helper module, but you just pass knex (containing its connection pool) for the helper methods so that all queries will share the same connection pool.

ORM's like objection.js also provides a way to extend query builder API so you can inherit custom query builder with any special query helper that you need.